# How can I duplicate each item in a Java list using a stream?

Tags: java, list, java-stream

I need to duplicate items in a `List`.

So, if the list is:

```json
["firstItem", "secondItem"]
```

I want to return a list that is:

```json
["firstItem","firstItem","secondItem","secondItem"]
```

I'm trying to do this through the `flatMap` function but I'm not sure how to go about doing it.

```java
List<T> duplicatedList = originalList.stream()
            .flatMap(u -> Stream.of()) // how to duplicate items??
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create a Stream of two identical items :

```
List<String> originalList = Arrays.asList("firstItem","secondItem");
List<String> duplicatedList = originalList.stream()
        .flatMap(u -> Stream.of(u,u))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(duplicatedList);
```

Output :

```
[firstItem, firstItem, secondItem, secondItem]
```

Comment: What is the advantage of using stream and collect in this case. I think questions boils down to advantage of using add vs addAll.

Comment: @Eran, is it possible to duplicate just specific items? I mean if(u.equals(something)) ...?

Comment: @Thend Of course. Just the the `.flatMap` to `.flatMap(u -> u.equals(something) ? Stream.of(u,u) : Stream.of(u))`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is simple and more readable:

```
 originalList.addAll(originalList);
```

Output :

```
 [firstItem, secondItem, firstItem, secondItem]
```

Comment: Actually your code would produce `[firstItem, secondItem, firstItem, secondItem]`, so if the order matters, it doesn't give the desired output.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i did not notice the order. Now corrected my output.